# Using Sprockets in Coffeescript, how do you //require?

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sprockets, middleman

Currently, I have my all.js file with this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.nicescroll.min
//= require bootstrap.min

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    $('html').niceScroll();

});
```

I would like to move it into an all.js.coffee, complying with the instrucions [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). How do I go about doing that because the `//=` results in a compile error.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.nicescroll.min
//= require bootstrap.min

$(document).ready ->
    $('.carousel').carousel()
    $('html').niceScroll()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#supported-comment-types):

> **Supported Comment Types**
>
> The directive processor understands comment blocks in three formats:
>   [...]
>
> ```
> # Single-line comment blocks (CoffeeScript)
> #= require foo
> ```

so presumably you'd say:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery.nicescroll.min
#= require bootstrap.min

$(document).ready ->
    $('.carousel').carousel()
    $('html').niceScroll()
```